# android looking for camera

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to follow the directions in the android development docs that deals with building a camera app.  So the first step in the docs were to see if the device that your app is on even has a camera at all.  So i built a simple code that should search my device (in this case the emulator) and find if it has a camera or not.  If it does create a textveiw and display "yes", if not create a textveiw and display "no".  But all it does is run and display the text in the main layout.xml which is "hello world".  My code is posted below any help would be apprecicated.

```
 package com.example.cam_test2;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);

        TextView myText = new TextView(this);
        myText.setText("yes");

        lView.addView(myText);

        setContentView(lView);
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        LinearLayout lView = new LinearLayout(this);

        TextView myText = new TextView(this);
        myText.setText("no");

        lView.addView(myText);

        setContentView(lView);

        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try to add Permission to Manifest file ?

Comment: do you google any example of camera and try yourself?

Comment: i added permissions and still nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your checkCameraHardware(this) within your onCreate method so it will run as activity is launched.